# AJAX success response not working Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a mailer that is successfully sending using AJAX, but when the submit button is clicked, it is left depressed and no success message is displayed.  Clicking the button multiple times results in multiple form submissions.  The button should reset, and (from my understanding) the AJAX:success event should generate some sort of text to show it was successful.

The AJAX Script (from [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers))

```
<script>
$(document).ready ->
  $("#AJAX-form").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#AJAX-form").append xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#AJAX-form").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
</script>
```

The (UPDATED) form:

```
<%= form_tag("/pages/thank_you", remote: true, id: 'AJAX-form') do %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="input-group">
              <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Name' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
            <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group text-area-wide">
              <%= text_area_tag :message, nil, class: 'form-control text-area-wide', placeholder: 'Message' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <%= submit_tag 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  <% end %>
```

The controller action:

```
def thank_you
    @name = params[:name]
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = params[:message] || "Hello!"
    UserMailer.contact_form(@email, @name, @message).deliver
end
```

Comment: `$("#AJAX-form")` is looking for an element with id="AJAX-form". Your form appears to have class="AJAX-form".

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your JavaScript bindings.

```
$("#AJAX-form").on(...)
```

is looking for an element with **id**="AJAX-form". Your form appears to have **class**="AJAX-form".

Either bind to the class with

```
$(".AJAX-form").on(...)
```

or change your form id to match

```
<%= form_tag("/pages/thank_you", remote: true, id: 'AJAX-form') do %>
```

Comment: Updated the code with this corrected code, but the original issue is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

From 1.9 version ajaxSuccess can be attached just only on the document object. 
"$(document).ajaxSucces(function(){...});"

But you can use the following code:

```
$('form').submit(
    function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data:data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            success: function( result ) {
                $form.trigger('submit:success');
            },
            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                console.log( "Status: " + status );
                console.dir( xhr );
                $form.trigger('submit:error');
            },
            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                $form.trigger('submit:complete');
                console.log( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    }
);


 $('form.SpecialForm').on('submit:success', myFunction1);

 $('form.OtherSpecialForm').on('submit:success', otherFunction);

 $('form.ThirdSpecialForm').on('submit:error', thirdFunction);

 $('form.OneMoreSpecialForm').on('submit:complete', oneMoreFunction);

 $('form.theLastSpecialForm').on('submit:complete', theLastFunction);
```